# Why does findIndex not return the first found element?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am looking for elements in an array with `findIndex`.

Here is the code:

```js
function findLower(element, index, tarray) {
  if (current_value >= element) {
    console.log("elected", element)
    return index
  }
}
const current_value = 15
const ordered_radiuses = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
const lower_index = ordered_radiuses.findIndex(findLower)
console.log("lower index", lower_index)
```

Which prints:

```
elected 0
elected 1
lower index 1
```

However, as 0 is lower than 15, and 0 being at index 0, I was expecting the output to be:

```
elected 0
lower index 0
```

What am I understanding wrong here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

> callbackFn
>
> A function to execute on each value in the array until the function returns true, indicating that the satisfying element was found.

You are returning `index` and not a boolean.

`0` is a false value.

`1` is a true value.

Replace `return index` with `return true` or, if you don't need the logging, replace the whole `if` statement with `return current_value >= element`

Answer (score 1):

It's almost fine, but you're returning the index and it's 0 on the first loop. And as 0 is handled as false it's going to the second value of your array. So that's how it must look like:

```
function findLower(element, index, tarray) {
  if (current_value >= element) {
    console.log("elected", element);
    return true;
  }
}
const current_value = 15;
const ordered_radiuses = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30];
const lower_index = ordered_radiuses.findIndex(findLower);
console.log("lower index", lower_index);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a `predicate` to `findIndex` and should return either `true` or `false` and you are returning the `index` which would produce the unexpected result

```js
function findLower(element, index, tarray) {
  return current_value >= element;
}
const current_value = 15;
const ordered_radiuses = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30];
const lower_index = ordered_radiuses.findIndex(findLower);
console.log("lower index", lower_index);
```

Comment: I'd guess because it is a code-only answer. It's spot-the-difference  and completely devoid of anything resembling an explanation for why the changes solve the problem.